# How to implement implicitly casts?

Tags: c#, properties, casting

I see that some properties allow beeing `casted implicitly`. Like `DataTable.Rows` cann be castet in `DataRow` and in `DateRowView`.

```
void DemoFunc()
{
    DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
    {


    }

    foreach (DataRowView row in dtTable.Rows)
    {

    }
}
```

I could use this behaviour in my own code. Does anybody know a simple example to understand how it works?

**Edit:**

What is my goal?
I wonder if its possible to design code like that:

```
Void DemoFunc2()
{

MyObject myObjec = new MyObject()

OtherObject otherObject = myObject.Property;
DifferentObject differentObject = myObject.Property;

}
```

Can  a property return diffent object-types?

**Edit 2:**

In this question are mixed two different things. Once the wondering about how to get a property with two different return types, based on the missunderstandig on how DataTable.Rows is designed.

Comment: A child class can always be converted to parent class.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal That is entirely correct, but of course completely irrelevant to this question since these two classes are not related.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but maybe this can be useful? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: @Dennis_E yes, this answers the 2nd part of my question. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: that doesn't work:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

However, `foreach` works on a pattern that allows, in some cases, implicit casts. Whether or not they work. In this example, it cannot be checked by the compiler because `.Rows` exposes an `object`-based iterator (in this case, `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator`, but even that is not strictly necessary).

More generally, there is the implicit conversion operator, but that still wouldn't apply with an `object`-based iterator, because operators are applied against statically known types only (unless you use `dynamic`).

In the scenario where the `GetEnumerator()` method allows access to something more than `object`, the compiler can tell us about this:

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dtTable.AsEnumerable())
{

}
```

to which the compiler adds an error:

> Error 1   Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Although in this scenario, it would at least allow implicit operators to be used, if defined. Which they aren't.

---

More detail:

### Why does it compile?

`.Rows` is typed as `DataRowCollection`. Since this dates back to .NET 1.1, it implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, but it was never updated to implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  Likewise, the `GetEnumerator()` method returns `IEnumerator` - not something more specific.

The problem with `IEnumerator` (as different to `IEnumerator<T>`) is that the `.Current` is typed only as `object`, because .NET 1.1 and C# 1.2 didn't have generics. It would have been very awkward if you had to do:

```
foreach(object tmp in table.Rows)
{
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)tmp; // this is our known-bad code
    // ...
```

so for convenience, the language **allows you to do that implicitly**, i.e. the above is roughly identical to:

```
foreach(DataRowView row in table.Rows) // this is our known-bad code
{
    // ...
```

What this *actually* becomes is something like:

```
{
    IEnumerator iter = table.Rows.GetEnumerator();
    // note this ^^^ is disposed after the loop if IDisposable; not shown
    while(iter.MoveNext())
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView) iter.Current; // .Current is: object
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notice how there is a cast from `object` to `DataRowView`? If the thing returned from `.Current` is not actually a `DataRowView` (and: it isn't), that will only fail **at runtime**, when the cast is performed. If we do the same thing with `DataRow` instead of `DataRowView`, it would have succeeded.

Note that the `foreach` pattern doesn't actually depend on `IEnumerator`; it is also possible for any type to have a `GetEnumerator()` method, and return a custom iterator type that has a stronger (typed) `.Current` implementation. If `DataRowCollection` had done this, **your code with `DataRowView` would fail. This could be a completely custom iterator, or could be simply `IEnumerable<DataRow>` / `IEnumerator<DataRow>`. Consider the entirely hypothetical:

```
{
    IEnumerator<DataRow> iter = table.Rows.GetEnumerator();
    // note this ^^^ is disposed after the loop if IDisposable; not shown
    while(iter.MoveNext())
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView) iter.Current; // .Current is: DataRow
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now with this construct, we can see that we are casting from `DataRow` to `DataRowView`, and **that** is something that the compiler can check at compile-time. Since they are classes, it will fail unless there is either an inheritance relationship, or a custom conversion operator. Since neither exists: it will fail.

Comment: Perhaps add some more information with links to the relevant documentation on how to implement those implicit casts. Since the OP seems to use the code as an example of what he wants to do, perhaps his code doesn't have this particular problem and could actually benefit from the implicit casts.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Dennis_E has already done that; not sure it is beneficial to duplicate

Comment: @Marc Gravell It works when there are no rows in the table. You are right with the exception when the tabel is filled. This doesn't make it easier for me to understand it.

Comment: @boboes of course it works when there are no rows: at runtime, it loops over the zero rows, and for each of the zero, it attempts to cast something from `object` to `DataRowView`. And for all zero rows, it fails. Zero failures can look an awful lot like success. I will edit my answer to explain more...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: `.. exposes an object-based ...` this makes it understandable for me and explains why row is of type object when unsing (var row in dtTable.Rows)

Comment: @boboes your point about `var row in dtTable.Rows` and `row` then being `object` is exactly right. In terms of the expansion, that is basically `var row = iter.Current;`

Comment: @Marc Gravell perfect, thanx. In my question I mixed two different things. Your explanation is very helpfull to me.